# solidity ..which hashing algorithm to use?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, keccak

I have tried using many hashing algorithms but there output in solidity doesn't match with the one given in online converters.

```
Here is my program:-
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;  
contract C {  
bytes32 public temp;  
function hashingsha3 (uint s)   {  
temp= sha3(s);  
}

    function hashingsha256 (uint s) {
        temp= sha256(s); 
    }
     function kec (uint s)   returns  (bytes32 hash){
        temp= keccak256(s); 
    }

}
```

[this is the online site to convert](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_512.html)

I have read solidity doesn't use the current keccak256 approved by NIST.
But then what does it use that matches any online output?
Any help would be useful.

List of outputs :
Solidity
sha3(12)
0xdf6966c971051c3d54ec59162606531493a51404a002842f56009d7e5cf4a8c7

sha256(12)
0xa82872b96246dac512ddf0515f5da862a92ecebebcb92537b6e3e73199694c45

keccak256(12)
0xdf6966c971051c3d54ec59162606531493a51404a002842f56009d7e5cf4a8c7

online converter
SHA256(12)
6b51d431df5d7f141cbececcf79edf3dd861c3b4069f0b11661a3eefacbba918

SHA512/256 (12)
d0d0b58b8cad7a27781cb78b3212d8abce1a4eb4192882e703f7f2e1ea5158da

SHA3-256(12)
1a9a118cb653759c3fcb3bd5060e6f9910c8c27008dd11fe4315f4635c9caa98

SHA3-512 (12)
f235c129089233ce3c9c85f1d1554b9cb21952b27e0765bcbcf75d550dd4d2874e546889da5c44db9c066e05e268f4742d672889ff62fb9cb18a3d1b57f00658

Keccak-256 (12)
7f8b6b088b6d74c2852fc86c796dca07b44eed6fb3daf5e6b59f7c364db14528

Thankyou

EDITED:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;  
contract C {  
bytes32 public temp;  
function hashingsha3 (bytes s)   {  
temp= sha3(s);  
}  
function hashingsha256 (bytes s) {  
temp= sha256(s);  
}  
function kec (bytes s)  {  
temp= keccak256(s);  
}  
}
```

I changed the code :
but still the outputs now for this are:
Passed as a string in solidity:
sha256(12)
0xe3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

sha3(12)
0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470

keccak256(12)
0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKYle.png)

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking why are the hashed outputs of solidity and online converter different.What should I use if I wish to confirm it with online converters.

Answer (score 3):

Completely agree with Mr. Marx. I'm just adding another answer as a commentary for consideration.

Your question turns attention to a hidden assumption. That is, that it's currently possible and convenient to find a suitable library for any given client, *and always will be*.

*In my opinion*, it would be a good idea to expose read-only function to assist clients and to provide a guarantee that they will always be able to compute the hash by the same method as today's compiled contract. Something simple ...

```
function hashHelper(uint value) public pure returns(bytes32 hash) {
  return keccak256(value);
}
```

The idea would be to use the same function internally, thus avoiding possible future divergence between the compiled bytecode and clients of all shapes and sizes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I din't really understand what do you mean.Are you saying I should just have returned instead of declaring temp public ?

Comment: It might be more clear if/when you write the client-side to this, that is, work out the library and syntax to use to successfully compute a hash the same way the contract does. The method suggested will greatly simplify that as well as help future-proof it.

Comment: amazing answer, thanks, Mr. Hitchens!

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is that in your Solidity code, you're hashing numbers, while the online converter you're using is hashing strings.

If you do `keccak256("12")` instead of `keccak256(12)`, you'll get a hash matching the one on the website.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it is still not working.

Comment: What do you mean "not working?" What's your current code, what result are you getting, and what are you getting from the website you found?

Comment: I edited the question in which I posted the current code and the results.

Comment: It's unclear how you're calling the functions, but my guess is you're still passing numbers instead of strings.

Comment: Make sure you have quotes around 12, like this: `"12"`.

Comment: If you're using Remix, you'll have to pass the hexadecimal representation. `web3.fromAscii("12") == "0x3132"`, so type `0x3132`. (As an alternative, you could accept a `string` instead of `bytes`. Then you can just pass `12`.)

Comment: Yes I was passing numbers like 12. Now I tried passing "12" in kec function which give output:0xb884017cbf765abdf2704fdfd3bf0dccb319a13e3927726e8b48123c74895f8c

Comment: Which still doesn't match.

Comment: You'll have to explain how you're calling the function. `web3.js`? `web3.py`, `truffle`? If any of those, share your code. If something else, share the code or the tool you're using. Maybe use screenshots if necessary.

Comment: BTW, `0xb884017...` is what you get when you hash the string `"12"` _including_ the double quotes (e.g. if you passed something like `'"12"'`). So this is just an encoding problem... wherever you're typing `"12"` in quotes, the quotes are being converted as well.

Comment: I am deploying the code and interacting with it on myetherwallet using ganache.