# How to use bytes to get the same hashed output

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, ganache, keccak

I previously asked a question here: [link to previous question.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/50986/solidity-which-hashing-algorithm-to-use)

Found out the answer is to use string instead of bytes here:

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract C { 
    bytes32 public temp;

    function hashingsha3 (bytes s)   {
        temp= sha3(s);
    }

    function hashingsha256 (bytes s) {
        temp= sha256(s); 
    }
     function kec (bytes s)  {
        temp= keccak256(s); 
    }

}
```

To get the matching hash.
However my question now is how to take input in bytes and not with "" to still get the correct answer.
Thankyou

Comment: Just input the value in hex (`0x1234....5`)

Comment: so if I want to enter 12 should I enter 0xc or 0x12?

Comment: depends if you're talking about `12` as number or `12` as string. the number is `0xC` while the string would be `0x3132`